# Multiple Threads on Multi-Core machine......but no performance boost

Tags: java, multithreading

The question is related to making a sequential program parallel.

i have a list of objects which does some evaluation on a dataset and returns results.
As of now, this is done in a loop (i.e. sequential way) - So, for each object we call the evaluate method and then the next....

Below shown is the output for single thread where we have different objects with IDs 101,102,104 ...
and these are run in sequential manner.

```
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 101)(startTime - 1416904532993)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 101) (endTime - 1416904540686) (Time Elapsed - 7693)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 102) (startTime - 1416904540686)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 102) (endTime - 1416904543433) (Time Elapsed - 2747)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 104) (startTime - 1416904543433)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 104) (endTime - 1416904543489) (Time Elapsed - 56)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 105) (startTime - 1416904543489)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 105) (endTime - 1416904543515) (Time Elapsed -  26)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 106) (startTime - 1416904543515)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - FirstThread)(Id - 106) (endTime - 1416904543804) (Time Elapsed - 289)
```

Now, i have modified it to use multiple threads, in this case i have 2 threads - Thread 1 (Will work on combined data set for object id 101 and 104 , Thread 2 (Will work on 102,105 and 106).
So, internally they will be sequential.

Following is the output for this case -

```
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread2) (Id - 102) (startTime - 1416900239970)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread1) (Id - 101) (startTime - 1416900240221)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread1) (Id - 101) (endTime - 1416900248122) (Time Elapsed - 7901)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread1) (Id - 104) (startTime - 1416900248122)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread1) (Id - 104) (endTime - 1416900248185) (Time Elapsed - 63)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread2) (Id - 102) (endTime - 1416900250410) (Time Elapsed - 10440)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread2) (Id - 105) (startTime - 1416900250410)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread2) (Id - 105) (endTime - 1416900250433) (Time Elapsed - 23)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread2) (Id - 106) (startTime - 1416900250433)
ForEachObject : (ThreadName - Thread2) (Id - 106) (endTime - 1416900250747) (Time Elapsed - 314)
```

As can be seen Thread1 and Thread2 are interleaved, but Thread1 for Object Id 102 starts and in between Thread2 for Object Id 101 and 104 completes and Thread1 seems to take more time.

My Question is - I have a quad core machine then why is time for Thread1 Object Id 102 is more as if everything is working in the same core. I am not getting any gains Over here.

Please help!!!

Thanks

Comment: And what about the code?

Comment: Plz post your code. There are countless possibilities why you can't get a speed-up.

Comment: without more information it is impossible to give you a definite answer - but the bottom line is generally that one (or more) resource is creating a bottleneck, for example: a file that is being read or a synchronized method or a database access or ...

Comment: also, for getting better insights faster, you might want to clean up your output. I always find it hard to read 21421-digit numbers.
Since nobody know what your code does: If you have outliers in your processing time by 3 orders of magnitude, you will not get much overalle speedup. Anyway, stop thinking about threads and start using a `ThreadPool`. These are well-documented.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Got some idea why is it taking more time. It is because of our design where in we look for best results and then do not look further. So, for multithreading case it was going much deeper and hence took more time.

Comment: Ralf H - Thanks for the suggestion but we cannot use Thread Pool because of some inherent issues. I had used threadpool first but had to resort to grouping the collections.